# Send picture in Windows 8 Messenger

Tags: windows-8, windows-live-messenger

In previous versions of Windows Live Messenger, it was possible to send an image in a conversation, either by dragging the file into the window or by pasting the image into the message box.

In the Windows 8 version, neither of these techniques work. How do you send a picture?

Comment: Are you referring to the built in "messaging" app?

Comment: Yes, I am. Am I wrong in thinking that the Messaging app is the same as Live Messenger?

Comment: @andypaxo - install the desktop version of the messaging application. The built-in application is at best the Metro version which given its not even been given a final release has lots of missing features.

Comment: Agreed with Andypaxo. The messaging app is intended to be chat only across many platforms. They may roll out that feature in a later release, but at current it is purely text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this Metro Messages program is still very basic and **adding attachements does not work so far** (just in Mail App it does). We all need wait for an update...

Until then, install the "old" desktop version of the live messenger

Answer (score 0):

As of 2013, Microsoft is transitioning Live Messenger users to Skype.

I'd advise anyone in this situation to install Skype, and sign in with the same account they used for MSN / Live Messenger. The interface is much nicer, there's both a desktop and Modern UI / "Metro" version.

This is what I'm doing now, although it wasn't an option when the question was originally asked.